# Audio over Displaylink USB 3.0

Tags: sound, displayport, displaylink

I have a DisplayLink USB 3.0 to DisplayPort adapter, connecting a Thinkpad laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 to a DisplayPort monitor.  When I installed the [DisplayLink Ubuntu driver](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/615714#ubuntu) and now the video on the monitor works fine, but audio doesn't seem to go through.  Under Settings->Sound I do see, in addition to "Built-In Audio", two entries labeled "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - USB3 to DP 55" and "Analog Output - USB3 to DP 55", but neither of them works: when selected, no sound comes out anywhere.

The DisplayLink page says

> Note: The DisplayLink .run file just provides support for the video outputs. Audio and Ethernet support are provided by the native Ubuntu drivers.

Does that mean that audio can't be sent over the USB adapter using the DisplayLink adapter?  Or that I have to set up a different driver for it?

Answer (score 2):

Audio definitely can be sent over display link because I had it working using the 5.2.14 driver on Ubuntu 18.04.

After I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and use the 5.3 driver sound has stopped working and I get the symptoms you explain (I can see the outputs presented by the displaylink hub, but changing to them still causes sound to play from the laptop).

I got sound working again by disabling PulseAudio's module `module-suspend-on-idle` as [described on the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink#Displays_disconnect_at_random_intervals_when_using_the_Dell_D6000_docking_station).

Comment: I have this problem but `module-suspend-on-idle` is already disabled for another reason... :-(